# Cygwin has no watch command?

Tags: cygwin, watch

I installed Cygwin on my Windows XP to use some of its commands. Now I what to check a file every 2 minutes and want to use watch for this purpose but I see that Cygwin has no such command. Is this really true? what can I do instead?

Comment: You can find out which Cygwin packages provide which files and programs at http://cygwin.com/packages/

Answer (score 98):

There is `watch` in cygwin. But it isn't installed by default. You need to install [`procps-ng`](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/procps-ng/) package to appear `watch`. (you can run cygwin installer again and it allows to install only the missed packages without reinstalling the whole cygwin)

Instead of `watch` you can use simple cycle like:

```
while true ; do check file ; sleep 2 ; done
```

where `check` is your command of choice.

Comment: Is 'check' a command, or are you including it as a placeholder? I literally pasted this and I just got a sequence of `-bash: check: command not found`. The cygwin installer doesn't seem to know anything about it ...

Comment: @robert, it is a placeholder.

Answer (score 39):

`watch` is included in [`procps-ng`](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/procps-ng/), so you should install the `procps-ng` package for Cygwin.

Answer (score 12):

Apparently [procps](https://cygwin.com/packages/procps/) is outdated, `watch` can now be found in the [procps-ng](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) package.

Answer (score 4):

Installed the ncurses package and then I get a `clear` screen on every run.  Thank you rush.

I ran mine as

```
while true ; do clear; <command> <file> ; sleep 2 ; done
```

such as

```
while true ; do clear; grep ERROR server.log | tail -n 5 ; done
```